# Take away a single day using Calendar in Java?

Tags: java, android, calendar, google-fit

I have an application that plugs into the Google Fit Api and returns the steps for the last 7 days, the method is below. As the screen shot shows though I wish to add the day to the step count.

I have tried many options to take away one day at a time for the 7 loop but had no luck, it just says the same day. Any help would be great thank you.

```
private void dumpDataSet(DataSet dataSet) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Data returned for Data type: " + dataSet.getDataType().getName());
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getTimeInstance();

    int i = 0;

    for (DataPoint dp : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {

        for(Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) { //loop 7 times

            int test = dp.getValue(field).asInt();

            String weekSteps= String.valueOf(test); //get weekday steps one at a time

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");



            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            String weekday = sdf.format(cal.getTime());

            String weekStepsFinal= weekSteps + " steps on " + weekday; //set Textfield to steps and the day 

            FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
            item.setTitle(weekStepsFinal);

            feedItemList.add(item);

        }
    }

}
```

There are 7 datasets btw.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "take away one day at a time" means that you want the days going backwards, then here's how:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");

System.out.println("Last 7 days (starting today):");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // Initialized to today/now
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    System.out.println("  " + sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1); // Update to previous day at same time-of-day
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Last 7 days (starting today):
  Monday
  Sunday
  Saturday
  Friday
  Thursday
  Wednesday
  Tuesday
```

Comment: Thank you changed abit but the idea was right :) Got it working in the end with your help

Answer (score 1):

This will subtract 7 days from the calendar to get you the date 7 days ago:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -7).
```

Comment: Note that this will roll over to previous months and years as you'd hope it would.

Answer (score 0):

To subtract one day use the following code :

```
int DAY_IN_MILLIS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
Date currentDate = new Date();
long previousDay = currentDate.getTime()-DAY_IN_MILLIS;

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
String day = sdf.format(previousDay);
```